# Insert Null value to the Integer Column

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, null, int

Through the front end I want to insert NULL value to the Column whose DataType is Int.

I used like this:

```
POP.JobOrderID = Convert.ToInt32(DBNull.Value);
```

But I cannot Insert Null value, it throws error such as "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types":

How to insert NULL values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you wish to do it `POP.JobOrderID` should be type `int?` ([nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) int) not int

Comment: POP is an Object and JobOrderID is an Int. How to assign like this?

Comment: I am using three tier architecture. I would pass parameter like above what i had given in the Question. How to apply int?(nullable) in this?

Answer (score 5):

kleinohad is correct. Furthermore, you should assign `null`, not `DBNull.Value`

Comment: I am using three tier architecture. I would pass parameter like above what i had given in the Question. How to apply int?(nullable) in this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Nullable<Int32>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) or just an alias: `int?`.

```
POP.JobOrderID = 5;
// or
POP.JobOrderID = null;
```

Usage in ADO.NET:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobOrderId", POP.JobOrderID ?? DBNull.Value);
```

which is equals to:

```
POP.JobOrderID.HasValue ? POP.JobOrderID.Value : DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```csh
   POP.JobOrderID = new Nullable<Int32>();
```

should work too IF the `JobOrderID` is a nullable type (`int?`).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 POP.JobOrderID = null;    // JobOrderID should be of type int? which is a nullable-int
```

Hope that helps.